# Append not working like expected

Tags: python, list, append

i have the following Problem:
For a genetic algorithm i'm creating 5 mutations and store them in a prepared list (see code below).

This is my function where i want to append the mutated drivers:

```
def startNewRunFromScratch(self):
    self.log.logBlue('Starting new run from scratch', 2, 0)
    parameterSet = []
    parameterSet.append(Parameter('TEST', 0.5, 0, 1))

    defaultGDriver = GDriver(parameterSet)
    gDriverList = []
    gDriverList.append(defaultGDriver)
    m = Mutation(self.mutationRate)
    for i in range(1, self.populationSize, 1):
        g = m.mutate(defaultGDriver)
        self.log.log('After mutaion: '+str(g.parameterSet[0].value), 0, 2)
        gDriverList.append(g)
    self.startSuite(gDriverList)
```

And here the the startSuite prototype function:

```
def startSuite(self, gDriverList):
    self.log.logSuccess('Starting suite', 1, 0)
    for g in gDriverList:
        self.log.log('Inside suite: '+str(g.parameterSet[0].value), 0, 2)
```

The problem is, that the output does not match my logic:

```
Starting new run from scratch
        After mutaion: 0.5
        After mutaion: 0.5
        After mutaion: 0.5
        After mutaion: 0.740296236666

Starting suite
        Inside suite: 0.740296236666
        Inside suite: 0.740296236666
        Inside suite: 0.740296236666
        Inside suite: 0.740296236666
        Inside suite: 0.740296236666
```

The expected output:

```
Inside suite: 0.5
Inside suite: 0.5
Inside suite: 0.5
Inside suite: 0.5
Inside suite: 0.740296236666
```

Does anyone have an good idea how to solve this problem? Maybee im missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You repeatedly append the same `Mutation`, and end up with multiple references to it in the list.  If you want different `Mutations`, you have to make new ones.  (I assume that's what you think is the "problem", as you never explicitly say what is wrong about the output.)

Comment: with m.mutate() i'm creating new ones. See log after mutation

Comment: @johni07: That logs the current value of `g`; it does not tell you if `g` is a new object or not.  That all of the objects in your list "magically" take on the last value strongly suggests they are all the same object.